# Adding pan/touch/drag in Custom SupportMapFragment in sherlockfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, supportmapfragment

I m trying to add a custom [pan/touch/drag on SupportMapFragment](http://dimitar.me/how-to-detect-a-user-pantouchdrag-on-android-map-v2/) in a sherlock framgment but I m  getting this logcat. what I m doing wrong here?

```
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to custom.widgets.CustomMapFragment
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at fragment.lifestyle.LifeStyle.onActivityCreated(LifeStyle.java:171)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-23 13:36:19.725: E/AndroidRuntime(10848):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my CustomMapFrament.java

```
package custom.widgets;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
public View mOriginalContentView;
public TouchableWrapper mTouchView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent,
            savedInstanceState);
    mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
    mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);
    return mTouchView;
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return mOriginalContentView;
}

}
```

and here is my TouchableWrapper.java file

```
public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

private long lastTouched = 0;
private static final long SCROLL_TIME = 100L; // 100 Milliseconds, but you
                                                // can adjust that to your
                                                // liking
private UpdateMapAfterUserInterection updateMapAfterUserInterection;

public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Force the host activity to implement the
    // UpdateMapAfterUserInterection Interface
    try {
        updateMapAfterUserInterection = (UpdateMapAfterUserInterection) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement UpdateMapAfterUserInterection");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        lastTouched = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (now - lastTouched > SCROLL_TIME) {
            // Update the map
            updateMapAfterUserInterection.onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection();
        }
        break;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

// Map Activity must implement this interface
public interface UpdateMapAfterUserInterection {
    public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection();
}
}
```

and here is My fragment (Lifestyle.java) extending the SherlockFragment.

```
public class LifeStyle extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener,
    UpdateMapAfterUserInterection {

private View v;

private GoogleMap map;

private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private CustomMapFragment mapFragment;


public LifeStyle() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (v != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(v);
    }
    try {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lifstyle_fragment, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }



    return v;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (CustomMapFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.rel_map);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = (CustomMapFragment) SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.rel_map, mapFragment).commit();
    }
}

    @Override
public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

and here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


            <My other views>


        </RelaytiveLayout>
</RelaytiveLayout>
```

**I have tried this code with the Activity it works perfect but in fragment it crashs** with the logcat given above. how to resolve this

Comment: As a warning, please do not use comments to demand that people answer your question here. I just removed all of these from across the site.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
mapFragment = (CustomMapFragment) SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
```

`SupportMapFragment.newInstance()` will create a `SupportMapFragment` instance, not your custom class. You probably meant to write:

```
mapFragment = new CustomMapFragment();
```